# How to use native APIs in NativeScript?

Tags: android, ios, swift, angular, nativescript

I'm building an app that will need to use native APIs, but actually using these APIs is proving extremely difficult as many arguments do not have clear analogs in TypeScript, definitions are missing, etc. How do people actually build with NativeScript?

As an example, I'm trying to use Apple's Secure Enclave to produce a public-private keypair following [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave) page. These snippets are written in Swift (I think), so many aspects of the syntax do not exist in typescript. After hours of trial and error, I've come up with arguments that don't cause errors. But then the `privateKey` value I get is null.

There is probably dozens or a hundred different permutations of arguments I could try that are *sort* of equivalent to the Swift code... This can't be how people build on NativeScript? I've looked everywhere, I've asked on the NativeScript Slack, I've read posts...

```
tns create
(choose Angular and hello-world)
npm install --save-dev tns-platform-declarations
```

Add `reference.d.ts` in the project root. Put the following in it:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
```

Update `tsconfig.json` so the `paths` looks like this:

```
"~/*": ["src/*", "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*", "./node_modules/*"]
```

Modify `app.component.html` to have just a button

```
<Button (tap)="onTap()"></Button>
```

Modify `app.component.ts` adding the code for the button:

```
    onTap() {
        const access = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
            kCFAllocatorDefault,
            kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
           SecAccessControlCreateFlags.kSecAccessControlPrivateKeyUsage,
            new interop.Pointer(0)
        );
        const attributes = {
            kSecAttrKeyType: 'type',
            kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: '256',
            kSecAttrTokenID: kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
            kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: {
                kSecAttrIsPermanent: 'true',
                kSecAttrApplicationTag: '<# a tag #>',
                kSecAttrAccessControl: 'access',
            },
        };
        const privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes as any, new interop.Pointer(0));
        console.info(privateKey);
    }
```

I'm sure there are many problems with my interpretation (shown above) of the Swift code. A solution to that would be nice. But my real question is how do people actually build with Angular (meant NativeScript)? I can't just guess what these params should be in typescript!

Expected result:

privateKey not null, a sensible way to access native APIs?

Comment: You can start looking at Nativescript [Documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries) and then search for plugins that has iOS implementations like this [Geolocation](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/blob/master/src/geolocation.ios.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's not always easy to interpret exactly what to write based on the typings, so it does come down to practice and a bit of experience gained from searching through the iOS runtime repo (in the tests, issues, and even the code-base itself). And even the best of us may still "go mad" from time to time.

When browsing the Apple API docs, it's best to set the language to Obj-C (as it's the runtime that the TypeScript typings are generated from).

It also helps vastly if you're already familiar with exactly how to invoke the API (i.e. you've managed to get it working in a native app beforehand). Yes, this is tough territory for Swift developers.

At a guess, you need to clean up your `attributes` dictionary. I referred to the "Generating New Cryptographic Keys" documentation (linked below) to get a better idea of what values to feed in. Here's a stab at it:

```js
const access: any = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
    kCFAllocatorDefault,
    kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
    SecAccessControlCreateFlags.kSecAccessControlPrivateKeyUsage,
    new interop.Pointer(0)
);

const myTag: NSData = NSString.alloc().initWithString("com.example.keys.mykey")
                      .dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

// Will be marshalled into the necessary NSDictionary<any, any> type
const attributes: any = {
    kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 256,
    kSecAttrTokenID: kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
    kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: {
        kSecAttrIsPermanent: true, // Hopefully marshalls to "YES" if appropriate
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: myTag,
        kSecAttrAccessControl: access,
    },
};

const privateKey: any = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes, new interop.Pointer(0));
console.info(privateKey);
```

Caution: I haven't run the code. It could well still be wrong..!

References:

- Apple docs: [Storing Keys in the Secure Enclave](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave?language=objc)
- Generating New Cryptographic Keys: [Storing Keys in the Secure Enclave](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/generating_new_cryptographic_keys?language=objc#2863927)

> But my real question is how do people actually build with Angular? I can't just guess what these params should be in typescript!

Angular doesn't come into this; accessing native APIs is done the same way for all flavours of NativeScript. The various non-core flavours of NativeScript are simply for managing the UI differently (i.e. declaratively).

The TypeScript typings give fairly good guidance on what to write in, but it does take some extra experience to figure out how to interpret it. Part of the problem is that Obj-C doesn't map perfectly into TypeScript, but I'd say the NativeScript team have done an astounding job of it.

If it all seems too insurmountable, you can make a native module instead, writing in Obj-C (or Swift) and just expose simple API bindings to your native module. But expect to encounter a learning curve if you decide to go down that route, too!

If you come across any more problems, I'd recommend posting in the #ios channel in the [Slack forums](https://nativescriptcommunity.slack.com/messages/C0MMK3V32). There are some professionals in there who know this dark art inside and out, and who would be more than happy to help; it's just a question of catching them at the right time.

If it helps anyone coming across this post, I provide various different example snippets of iOS API invocation via NativeScript [here](https://github.com/shirakaba/nativescript-grimoire) – though I've not dealt with APIs from this Security framework before.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer. This is extremely helpful!